# How to use SocketIO event at different Vue components same time

Tags: vue.js, socket.io

I have 3 Components. App.vue, Header.vue and Example.vue

App.vue is my Parent component. Header.vue and Example.vue is my child components.

My Header.vue `created()` method :

```
created()
{
   socket.on('notification', data => {
     console.log('Header Page');
   });
}
```

My Example.vue `created()` method :

```
created()
{
   socket.on('notification', data => {
     console.log('Example Page');
   });
}
```

When page rendered, i see only **"Example Page"** at console. 
Only the last event is triggered when the event has the same name.

This is simple example. I use Vue Router and use socket only App.vue. For different operations, i check router name. It is very diffucult and complicated.

I want use different operations with same event name at different components.

I want output like this :

```
 Header Page
 Example Page
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible by using mixins in Vue js

Just create a file mixin.js in src directory

mixin.js

```
const myMixin = (value) => {
    return {
      created(){
        if (value) console.log(value);
      }
    }
}

export default myMixin;
```

In Header.vue import the mixin.js file

```
<script>
import myMixin from '../mixin.js';

export default {
    name: 'header-component',
    mixins: [myMixin("header page")],
  };
</script>
```

In Example.vue import the mixin.js file

```
<script>
import myMixin from '../mixin.js';

export default {
    name: 'example-component',
    mixins: [myMixin("example page")],
  };
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply @chans. But it is not working with **socket**. This problem is event problem. Your example work with normal functions. I wand same events not same functions.  Sorry for my english

Comment: Import socket object and use it in the mixin, source https://scotch.io/tutorials/extending-vue-components-with-mixins

Comment: Sorry. Same problem. I used but not working. Because socket event only 1 time